# Writing a User Defined Function for Ansys Fluent

Tags: fluid-mechanics, ansys, fluent

Is it only possible to write a User Defined Function for Ansys Fluent in C? All of the tutorials I could access online do so. I was wondering if this could be done using Java, or any other language for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to Ansys themselves the answer is clear :
Source is : http://www.ansys.com/services/training-center/fluids/ansys-fluent-using-user-defined-functions

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use only C language for writing UDF. As UDF is an add on customization of Fluent, you have to use C language.  Because all APIs are exposed in C language only.
For automating ANSYS Fluent you can use scheme language. 
In future ANSYS may provide multi language support, but as of now (ANSYS 19.2) there is support of only C language for writing UDFs.